# From what I studied IP address in subnet are generally in 2^x format but how do we solve this question as it is not possible to divide that way

Tags: networking, subnet

A company has been assigned the IP address range 192.168.22.0/24 for their network. They have two departments, sales and marketing, and each department requires a minimum of 100 IP addresses. The company also wants to reserve a block of IP addresses for their servers. How would you subnet the network to meet these requirements?

I thought of doing 128 for each department as that is closest to 100 but then there are no IP left for servers.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is still on a flat L2 network without internal routers, then reserving IP addresses is a purely administrative task.

If you want to use a router to subnet the /24, you will end-up with /25.

When you have a need for more internal IPs than you have been allocated, you will need to use a private space. For corporate use, it is customary to use 10.0.0.0/8. This means NATting towards the Internet, or using a proxy for the clients.

Basically, this means that you are on, or just over, the limit where you need to create a corporate network. I've stated simply, that that means NATting or a proxy, but it means a lot more than that. Security, which servers get external access, DMZ, name resolution DHCP et cetera.